# Which soc is redmi note 3 snapdragon?

Tags: hardware, arm-processors

I have a redmi note 3 snapdragon 650(which is supposed to be msm8956) variant.CPU-Z is showing my soc as msm8952 which is name for snapdragon 617.

Comment: I am also not able to install adreno drivers(using magisk or recovery) for snapdragon 650 it says that this is for msm8956 but your device is msm8952 I installed drivers for snapdragon 617 but then the phone doesn't boot.

Comment: https://youtu.be/snJXwL2WVDk I found this video of CPU z on redmi note 3 his phone too shows msm8952 in the system tab

Comment: Sorry, in the device tab not the system.

Comment: maybe you have other device "Redmi Note 3 **Pro**" (kenzo)

Answer (score 2):

I have faced something similar with my MTK G85 and this happens when your vendor (in your case xiaomi) does things in a hurry and uses some generic code/config files with SoCs similar to your one. For instance, my MTK G85 was detected as some MTK P series chip.

If you're already on the latest software version, try raising an issue in Xioami/redmi forums

Also, make sure you're not having Redmi Note 3 Pro which actually runs on an msm8952.